# Spring overloading

Tags: java, spring

I am having problems with overloading spring managed services. Basically it does not work as expected, and tested with normal java code. I was wondering if you can point me in the right direction, because now to have it working I need to make some ugly work. 
This is the simplification of code I have

```
public class Base{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Base");
    }
}
public class Extended extends Base {
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Extended");
    }
}

public interface Test{
    public method(Base b);
    public method(Extended b);
}


public class TestImpl implements Test{
    public method(Base b){
        b.print();
    }
    public method(Extended b){
        System.out.println("child")
        b.print();
    }
}
```

now when I invoke from a controller

```
Base b = new Extended();
test.method(b);
```

and only "Base" is printed
to have it working properly I use ugly:

```
if(b instanceof Extended){
    test.method((Extended)b);
}else {
    test.method(b);
}
```

This, from my undestanding of overloading, should happen automatically. It does when I invoke similar code in jUnit or sth. But when the Test Impl is a service in a spring container it does not work as expected

Comment: This does not have anything to do with Spring, and this is just how Java works. Which method is called is determined by the type of the variable, which is `Base`, and not the type of the actual object that the variable refers to (which is `Extended`). "This, from my undestanding of overloading, should happen automatically." => No, your understanding of calling overloaded methods is incorrect.

Comment: Please post your spring configuration/wiring

Comment: Jasper is right. I was using Spock-groovy to check it and it worked as I expected, that is what mislead me. When I moved it to jUnit to my suprise the result was different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you created a 
Base b = new Extended(); // Memory allocation of Extended class
test.method(b); // definitely it will call Extended=>print method

As mentioned in earlier comment differentiate it from different print statements so you can understand.

Comment: I was using Spock-groovy to check it and it worked as I expected, that is what mislead me. When I moved it to jUnit to my suprise the result was different. You are right

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to have different text to differentiate whether Base class's method or child class's method getting executed

```
public class Extended extends Base {
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Base - Extended");
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not resolve problem. In real code I had the "extended" print, I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

As you are on spring so [ Base b = new Extended() ] is not for spring, Spring do initialization of instance object itself in its container, you can use @Autowired to get an instance from container in your desired class.

Regarding you question of inheritance and overloading you check @Qualifier in spring. You can pin point exact the base class or which child class you want to get reference using @Qualifier annotation.